# Api called twice next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

wondering how this could happen when this get call API twice. I'am using nextjs with typescript and using and design.

Below my code

```
const EditRoles = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState();
  const [rolePermission, setRolePermission] = useState([]);
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState<Params>({
    page: 1,
    row: 10,
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(0);

  const getRolePermission = async (payload: { page?: number; row?: number; search?: string }) => {
    if (id) {
      setLoading(true);

      const res = await httpService
       .get(`${apiUrl.user}/v1/role-permission/${id}`, { params: payload })
       .then((resp) => resp);

      const rps = await res.data;

      setLoading(false);

      const roleP = rps.data.map((rp) => {
        return { ...rp };
      });

      setRolePermission(rps.page === 1 ? roleP : [...rolePermission, ...roleP]);
      setNextPage(rps.nextPage);
      setPagination({ ...pagination, page: pagination.page + 1 });
      console.log('this next page: ', rps.nextPage);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
   getDetailRole();
   getRolePermission({
     ...pagination,
   });
   form.setFieldsValue({
     name: detail,
     permissions: rolePermission,
   });
  }, [id, form, detail]);

 return (
  // ... HTML GOES HERE ... //
 );
};

export default EditRoles;
```

And below are this result for the code. [testing code](https://screenrec.com/share/PaMyRnvJQK)

My question is, why this api called twice and the pagination sometimes breaking like the video?

Please help what is wrong with the code.

Thank you

Comment: The function `getRolePermission` is async but you are not waiting until it's finished. If that's not the problem, it should be quite a spot like that.

Comment: So what should i change it? @DanielW.

Comment: Check out this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await